# Ajax url not working in laravel with angular.js

Tags: ajax, angularjs, laravel-4

I tried this code:

### Angular JS:

```
$http({
    method:"POST",
    url:baseurl+'/login',
    data:info
});
```

### routes.php

```
Route::get('/login', 'LoginController@doLogin');
```

### LoginController.php

```
public function doLogin()
{
    return json_encode( Input::all() );
}
```

Comment: i found it, i am using post method in js and have used get route in routes.php. :-)

Comment: Makes sense! It seems like you can safely delete this question since it was case specific and probably won't be helpful to others.